# How to create database for testing

Tags: 7, drush, testing

I'm implementing http://phactory.org/ to get away from the heavier aspects of test data creation.  One of the prerequisite items for this is to start with an empty database, with proper schema.

I need to do this in drush so I can incorporate this into Jenkins or another CI process.

The options as I see them are:

1) write my own drush command which copies a local db using sql-sync, but truncates the tables.  This seems brittle

2) create a test database and use [drupal_install_schema()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/7).

My current process is to take a schema-only copy of the db (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107919/copy-database-structure-without-data-in-mysql-with-empty-tables)) and then create a new test database from it.  In between tests, I just truncate the data.

What options am I missing to copy the schema from the drupal db to another test db to handle test data?

What is the better of the options?